# Tuning autovacuum for update heavy tables

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

I have a very update heavy table.
The problem is that the table grows a lot, as the autovacuum can not catch up. 
The autovacuum kick in every 2 minutes, so it is running file.

I have an application which is making like 50k updates(and a few inserts) every 60-70 seconds.

I am forced to do CLUSTER every week, which is not the best solution IMO.
My autovacuum settings are as follows (plus related):

```
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 10000
autovacuum_naptime = 10
autovacuum_max_workers = 5
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 10ms
vacuum_cost_limit = 1000
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.1 # this is set only for this table
```

Here is the autovacuum log:

> 2018-01-02 12:47:40.212 UTC [2289] LOG:  automatic vacuum of table
>   "mydb.public.sla": index scans: 1 pages: 0 removed, 21853 remain, 1
>   skipped due to pins, 0 skipped frozen tuples: 28592 removed, 884848
>   remain, 38501 are dead but not yet removable buffer usage: 240395
>   hits, 15086 misses, 22314 dirtied avg read rate: 29.918 MB/s, avg
>   write rate: 44.252 MB/s system usage: CPU 0.47s/2.60u sec elapsed 3.93
>   sec

It seems to me that 29 MB/s is way to low, considering my hardware is pretty OK

I have Intel NVMe devices, and my I/O doesn't seem to be saturated.

Postgresql version: 9.6
CPU : Dual Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz

Any ideas how to improve this?

Comment: Maybe this blog post will help. https://pganalyze.com/blog/visualizing-and-tuning-postgres-autovacuum/

Comment: Further reading: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/autovacuum-tuning-basics/ and https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/when-autovacuum-does-not-vacuum/